# where can I find fonts scanned from books?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I'm sure this has to exists but I can't find it.

I'm looking for fonts scanned from books, comic books or magazines. 
I want them *not* to be perfect, with some grain from the books paper, etc; but it should be subtle, I don't want a grungy font.

[image]

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: uh... Can I know why this has been downvoted ?

Comment: You probably were downvoted because you didn't explain what effort you've done (have you googled this to see if you could find something? If you did, did you find anything that was close-but-not-quite?). There are a lot of fonts that meet this criteria (I found [Misproject](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/misproject) in about 30 seconds) that meet this criteria, so some examples of what you tried that didn't work would be helpful.

Comment: Ok, i'll remember that.  Two things anyway : 1/ of course I googled this; otherwhise i would not loose time writing a question here...  2/ Misproject doesn't look like a font from a book at all.  It's kind of a grungy font, which I said I wasn't looking for... :)

Comment: I guess we had different definitions of "grungy"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some !  I think my favorite is [Appareo](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/kimmy-design/appareo).

[image: Appareo font by Kimmy Design]

Some others can be found in the *Historical Fonts* category of FontSpring.

Comment: Nice. Combine that with a paper texture and reduce the opacity of the text so that the texture shows through and you'l be winning.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question, then what you are looking for doesn't exist. Fonts are vector objects by definition which means that they have hard edges and can only include details that have hard edges. The kind up subtle, natural degradation that you are looking for would have a photographic quality, like a scan, as you suggest.

The route to the look that you want is more likely to come from superimposing an image with a bit of 'dirt' in it to degrade the text underneath or by rasterising the the text and applying filters to it (such as noise or blur).

You could of course go old school: print the text out, crumple the paper, wipe it across a dirty floor, whatever gives you the level of imperfection that you are looking for and then scan it back in.

Comment: Raster fonts do exist we just do nolonger suport them very well.

Comment: Yeah, you are understing my question !  Your answer seems logical.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There is no font that can do what you want... my apologies.
But there is some tricks to do (for print & web project).

---

If you want to use it for a website, this is not a good idea... but you can use this CSS properties :

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

This is not supported by every browser as you can see :

[image: Background-clip - caniuse]

---

If this is for a print project, you can add texture to your font in Photoshop with this, by double clicking your font layer :

[image]

OR

Use an image to make your font textured, like this :

[image]

---

I hope it will help you,
cheers.

Comment: Hi Mijer !  This is not what I'm looking for : your suggestion (for Photoshop) is to generate a noise and mask it with a (regular) font layer.  But what i'm interested in, is a font that has some glitches in it (look at the "p" or the "o" of the image) - which is quite different :)  Anyway, _merci_ for your reply !

Comment: Also, I would like to use it in a motion design video.  It's too much work to create all the required texts in Photoshop.  A font would be the best solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I know at least one such font that's free: https://www.feorag.com/freestuff/chapbook.html

I hope it's not *too* 17th-century.

[image: Chapbook font by Feòrag]